# What is the best way to update the Parse SDK for Android

Tags: android, parse-platform, sdk

I need to update the Parse SDK to remove a "dangerous" permission (GET_ACCOUNTS) that the updated SDK no longer requires. Are there any concerns about just swapping .jar files then re-building?

Comment: From my experience they tend to change a lot of thing from version to version, however you should give it a try.  Just make sure to not delete the older version just in case

Comment: Can I ask where did you see the updated SDK that no longer requires that permission? I still see it on their documentation [here](https://parse.com/apps/quickstart#parse_push/android/native/existing). If it's true they no longer needs it, it'd be great!